# Laptop cpu not maintaining turbo boost for more than a second on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, laptop, cpu

cpu - i7-8550u

problem is that my laptop's cpu is not maintaining turbo boost of 3.9ghz for more than a few seconds before dropping to base on ubuntu 20.04

as soon as i hit render it touches max frequency but after a couple of seconds it drops to base frequency

any solutions?

Edit :- temperature is not the issue , cpu jumps to 88-89°c for brief moment (when it's turboing) then hits base frequency and stay stable at 57-58°c

Comment: agree with answer, likely thermal. However suggest [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262768/does-sensors-command-show-accurate-temprature-of-cpu-cores/1262815#1262815) to monitor temp instead.

Comment: Still sounds like temperature is the issue. Depends on what trip points have been set in whatever thermal monitoring daemon you might be running. As a test, I suggest to limit your max CPU frequency such that you never hit the thermal trip point (if such exists). Assuming you are using the default intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver do `echo 60 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct` and gradually increase, under load, watching temp.

Comment: Oh, it could also be power limit throttling. Watch turbostat for that also.

Answer (score 0):

Laptops are more prone to cooling issues than regular systems... Could it be that your CPU is throttled because it gets too warm? If that is the case, the output of `dmesg` will report this. You can check the current temperature using the `sensors` command (from the `lm-sensors` package).

What is the cpu frequency governor you are currently using? You can check (and set) this with the utilities from the `cpufrequtils` package. Try `cpufreq-info | grep 'may decide which'`. But, pointing at the cpu frequency governor is a long shot; my system is using the 'powersave' governor, and I see my CPU at max speeds for long periods of time.

Comment: Temperatures hit high 80 for a brief moment when cpu hit max frequency but then stay stable at about 58°c for the rest of the time

Comment: 80 degrees is not too high. So that's probably not the problem. Does dmesg or log files show anything useful?